# Find all contexts in which a block appears

Tags: blocks, 7

Is there a quick way to find, for a particular block, all of the contexts that can display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly find all the contexts in which a block appears by performing a code search. Exported Contexts are placed inside `name_of_your_feature.context.inc` files. So when searching your Contexts for a particular block name you could restrict your search to `*.context.inc` files. Here's an example Zend Studio/Eclipse search as described above:

[image: Searching Contexts for particular Blocks]

My team generally puts Features (which contain exportables such as Contexts) in their own dedicated folder, making your code search faster and more efficient.

```
/modules
  /contrib
  /custom
    /features
```

Comment: Packaging exportables into Features allows you to export your contexts between different environments (Dev, QA, Prod) without much effort. It also provides you a backup of your settings in your code. Also from my experience, I would say it's pretty much common practice.